# python-certbot dependencies broken E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: python, debian, apt, debian-jessie

This is my problem, if someone can help me...

From a server which has been just upgraded from Debian 7 Wheezy to Debian 8 Jessie, some issues appear since the upgrade of  python-django for a  mumble server ; but above all trying to install certbot broke dependencies.

After this command
`apt-get install python-certbot-apache -t jessie-backports
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

some paquets python should been upgraded to a backport version, but it brokes dependencies...

last upgrade show these errors message (sorry locales are in french):

```
$ apt upgrade
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Calcul de la mise à jour... Fait
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
18 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/681 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
Paramétrage de python-augeas (0.5.0-1~bpo8+1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-augeas (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-cffi (--configure) :
 le paquet est dans un état vraiment incohérent; vous devriez
 le réinstaller avant de tenter de le configurer.
Paramétrage de python-configargparse (0.11.0-1~bpo8+1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-configargparse (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-pkg-resources (--configure) :
 le paquet est dans un état vraiment incohérent; vous devriez
 le réinstaller avant de tenter de le configurer.
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-six (--configure) :
 le paquet est dans un état vraiment incohérent; vous devriez
 le réinstaller avant de tenter de le configurer.
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de python-cryptography :
 python-cryptography dépend de python-cffi ; cependant :
 Le paquet python-cffi n'est pas encore configuré.
 python-cryptography dépend de python-pkg-resources ; cependant :
 Le paquet python-pkg-resources n'est pas encore configuré.
 python-cryptography dépend de python-six ; cependant :
 Le paquet python-six n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-cryptography (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Paramétrage de python-dnspython (1.15.0-1~bpo8+1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-dnspython (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Paramétrage de python-enum34 (1.0.3-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-enum34 (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Paramétrage de python-funcsigs (1.0.2-3~bpo8+1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-funcsigs (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Paramétrage de python-idna (2.0-3~bpo8+1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-idna (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Paramétrage de python-ipaddress (1.0.16-1~bpo8+1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-ipaddress (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de python-openssl :
 python-openssl dépend de python-cryptography ; cependant :
 Le paquet python-cryptography n'est pas encore configuré.
 python-openssl dépend de python-six ; cependant :
 Le paquet python-six n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-openssl (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Paramétrage de python-parsedatetime (1.4-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-parsedatetime (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Paramétrage de python-psutil (4.1.0-1~bpo8+1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-psutil (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-pyasn1 (--configure) :
 le paquet est dans un état vraiment incohérent; vous devriez
 le réinstaller avant de tenter de le configurer.
Paramétrage de python-pyicu (1.8-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-pyicu (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Paramétrage de python-rfc3339 (1.0-4~bpo8+1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-rfc3339 (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de python-setuptools :
python-setuptools dépend de python-pkg-resources (= 5.5.1-1) ; cependant :
 Le paquet python-pkg-resources n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python-setuptools (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
  python-augeas
  python-cffi
  python-configargparse
  python-pkg-resources
  python-six
  python-cryptography
  python-dnspython
  python-enum34
  python-funcsigs
  python-idna
  python-ipaddress
  python-openssl
  python-parsedatetime
  python-psutil
  python-pyasn1
  python-pyicu
  python-rfc3339
  python-setuptools
```

````

I have try lot of commands to resolve the issue like `apt-get autoclean`, `apt-get clean`, `apt -f install`, 
try to delete files .posinst in /var/lib/dpkg/info/ and make `apt-get -f install`, I try to come back also with `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python-augeas python-cffi python-six python-cryptography python-pyasn1 python-setuptools python-openssl pyrhon-certbot` , try with aptitude, no solution.

the hystory of the last apt commands in /var/log/apt/history.log:

> Start-Date: 2018-10-03  23:44:02 Commandline: apt-get install
>   python-certbot-apache -t jessie-backports Install:
>   python-funcsigs:amd64 (1.0.2-3~bpo8+1, automatic), python-acme:amd64
>   (0.10.2-1~bpo8+2, automatic), python-mock:amd64 (2.0.0-3~bpo8+1,
>   automatic), python-pbr:amd64 (1.8.0-4.1~bpo8+1, automatic),
>   python-certbot:amd64 (0.10.2-1~bpo8+1, automatic),
>   python-dnspython:amd64 (1.15.0-1~bpo8+1, automatic),
>   python-configargparse:amd64 (0.11.0-1~bpo8+1, automatic),
>   certbot:amd64 (0.10.2-1~bpo8+1, automatic), python-psutil:amd64
>   (4.1.0-1~bpo8+1, automatic), python-pyicu:amd64 (1.8-1, automatic),
>   python-cffi-backend:amd64 (1.9.1-2~bpo8+1, automatic),
>   python-zope.component:amd64 (4.2.1-2, automatic), python-augeas:amd64
>   (0.5.0-1~bpo8+1, automatic), python-certbot-apache:amd64
>   (0.10.2-1~bpo8+1), python-zope.interface:amd64 (4.1.1-3.1, automatic),
>   python-configobj:amd64 (5.0.6-1, automatic), python-zope.event:amd64
>   (4.0.3-2, automatic), python-idna:amd64 (2.0-3~bpo8+1, automatic),
>   python-ipaddress:amd64 (1.0.16-1~bpo8+1, automatic),
>   python-parsedatetime:amd64 (1.4-1, automatic), python-enum34:amd64
>   (1.0.3-1, automatic), python-rfc3339:amd64 (1.0-4~bpo8+1, automatic)
>   Upgrade: python-cffi:amd64 (0.8.6-1, 1.9.1-2~bpo8+1),
>   python-pyasn1:amd64 (0.1.7-1, 0.1.9-1~bpo8+1),
>   python-pkg-resources:amd64 (5.5.1-1, 33.1.1-1~bpo8+1),
>   python-setuptools:amd64 (5.5.1-1, 33.1.1-1~bpo8+1),
>   python-cryptography:amd64 (0.6.1-1+deb8u1, 1.7.1-3~bpo8+1),
>   python-six:amd64 (1.8.0-1, 1.10.0-3~bpo8+1), python-openssl:amd64
>   (0.14-1, 16.0.0-1~bpo8+1) Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an
>   error code (1) End-Date: 2018-10-03  23:44:19
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-03  23:55:08 Commandline: apt-get -f install
>   Remove: python-acme:amd64 (0.10.2-1~bpo8+2), python-mock:amd64
>   (2.0.0-3~bpo8+1), python-pbr:amd64 (1.8.0-4.1~bpo8+1),
>   python-certbot:amd64 (0.10.2-1~bpo8+1), certbot:amd64
>   (0.10.2-1~bpo8+1), python-cffi-backend:amd64 (1.9.1-2~bpo8+1),
>   python-certbot-apache:amd64 (0.10.2-1~bpo8+1) Error: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date: 2018-10-03 
>   23:55:16
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-03  23:57:05 Commandline: apt remove
>   python-certbot-apache -t jessie-backports Error: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date: 2018-10-03 
>   23:57:06
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-03  23:58:37 Commandline: apt-get autoremove
>   Remove: python-funcsigs:amd64 (1.0.2-3~bpo8+1), python-dnspython:amd64
>   (1.15.0-1~bpo8+1), python-configargparse:amd64 (0.11.0-1~bpo8+1),
>   python-psutil:amd64 (4.1.0-1~bpo8+1), python-pyicu:amd64 (1.8-1),
>   python-zope.component:amd64 (4.2.1-2), python-augeas:amd64
>   (0.5.0-1~bpo8+1), python-zope.interface:amd64 (4.1.1-3.1),
>   python-configobj:amd64 (5.0.6-1), python-zope.event:amd64 (4.0.3-2),
>   python-idna:amd64 (2.0-3~bpo8+1), python-ipaddress:amd64
>   (1.0.16-1~bpo8+1), python-parsedatetime:amd64 (1.4-1),
>   python-enum34:amd64 (1.0.3-1), python-rfc3339:amd64 (1.0-4~bpo8+1)
>   Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-03  23:58:39
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  00:01:51 Commandline: apt-get -f install
>   Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  00:01:53
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  00:15:02 Commandline: apt-get autoremove
>   Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  00:15:04
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  00:15:41 Commandline: apt install -f Error:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  00:15:43
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  00:18:06 Commandline: apt upgrade Error:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  00:18:08
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  01:08:53 Commandline: apt-get --purge remove
>   Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  01:08:54
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  01:12:40 Commandline: apt-get autoremove
>   Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  01:12:41
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  01:18:03 Commandline: apt-get -f install
>   Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  01:18:05
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  01:23:13 Commandline: apt-get -f install
>   Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  01:23:14
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  02:04:17 Commandline: apt upgrade Error:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  02:04:19
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  10:23:34 Commandline: apt upgrade Upgrade:
>   imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (6.8.9.9-5+deb8u13, 6.8.9.9-5+deb8u14),
>   imagemagick:amd64 (6.8.9.9-5+deb8u13, 6.8.9.9-5+deb8u14),
>   libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (6.8.9.9-5+deb8u13, 6.8.9.9-5+deb8u14),
>   imagemagick-common:amd64 (6.8.9.9-5+deb8u13, 6.8.9.9-5+deb8u14),
>   libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (6.8.9.9-5+deb8u13,
>   6.8.9.9-5+deb8u14), libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (6.8.9.9-5+deb8u13, 6.8.9.9-5+deb8u14) Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date: 2018-10-04  10:23:52
>
> Start-Date: 2018-10-04  10:40:49 Commandline: apt upgrade Error:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) End-Date:
>   2018-10-04  10:40:51

Can someone help me !!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your python 2.7 installation is broken. Please reinstall your python packages